# Could not working my fade in fade out when i displaying success message onsubmit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Could not working my fade in fade out when i displaying success message `onsubmit` function:

Here is my **Javascript**:

```
<script>
popUpForm = function() {
    jQuery('#successMessage').text("Successfully submitted !").fadeIn("slow")
    jQuery('#successMessage').css("display", "block")

    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#successMessage').fadeOut()
        jQuery('#successMessage').css("display", "none")
    }, 5000);
}
</script>  And Here is my message block div: <div th:id = "successMessage"  class="alert-box success"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

See using following code am not sure.

```
var auto_info = setInterval(function() {
        $("#successMessage").text("Successfully submitted !").fadeIn("successMessage");

    $("#successMessage").trigger('updatelayout');

    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#successMessage').fadeOut();
    }, 5000);

   });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need not set `display` property when using [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) / [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) functions as these functions themselves take care of hiding and showing elements with fading effect:

```
<script>
popUpForm = function() {
    jQuery('#successMessage').text("Successfully submitted !").fadeIn("slow");

    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#successMessage').fadeOut();
    }, 5000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank u, i tried this but still it can not handle setTimeout()..it shows me message block for few seconds and fadeOut instantly.

Comment: @Bohemian You can increase transition time while fading out by passing in "slow" parameter to `fadeOut()` function as you have done with `fadeIn("slow")` function. Please try it once.

Comment: No change, is there any way to display success message on submit? i tried one way that i passing message from controller as modelAndView.adObject("successMessage", "Successfully submitted");  but in this case when reload the page getting double entry of form in my database.  to avoid this i did redirect URL and showing message by using above javascript.

Comment: You just need to add some animation while your successMessage div gets hidden instantly, right? Though normally fadeOut() should be fine for that, may be something else on your webpage is conflicting with this. Can you try `slideUp("slow")` instead of `fadeOut()` once?